# google geo autocomplete showing options above input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

how to show google geo autocomplete suggested locations above the input box. By default it shows under the input box.

Updated code

```
$('#testinput').geo_autocomplete(new google.maps.Geocoder, {
        mapkey: 'ABQIAAAA9zwaGXY8VJfahtEvIhFqRxQxHJFQqLPid4j-bqIolB-PApACxRRl-6RW4s2FYG7jrEBuytEwCKb02Q',
        selectFirst: true,
        minChars: 3,
        cacheLength: 50,
        width: 200,
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 330,
        position: { my: 'left bottom', at: 'left top' }
    }).result(function (_event, _data) {
        if (_data) {
            try {
                map.fitBounds(_data.geometry.viewport)
            } catch (error) { }
        };
    });
```

Comment: A little more detail need here. What APIs, libraries or plugins are you using? Perhaps providing an example link would help.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.

In order to do this using geo-autocomplete, you would need to customise it so that you can allow a 'position' option to be passed to the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget that it makes use of.

I've made a quick demo here: http://jsbin.com/eyobi6

All this does is add the following line to 'ui.geo_autocomplete.js':

```
position: { my: 'left bottom', at: 'left top' },
```

You can place it anywhere within the options object, but I placed it after the following line:

```
delay: 300, // see http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-delay
```

Comment: Did you add the line to the 'ui.geo_autocomplete.js' file? Your updated code only implies that you simply added it to your geo_autocomplete method. Also, could you confirm whether my example provided works?

Comment: Yes I dont want to change the geo_autocomplete.js file, just want to pass parameter. Yes ur online code is working.

Comment: You simply wouldn't be able to do this without changing the geo_autocomplete.js file. The function inside it needs to pass the position to the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin, but it currently does not support doing so. The line of code I have added to the file adds this feature.